# .Dialog not showing on table cell click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

UPDATE: I am currently stuck with this code not showing a dialog on click.:
The problem now is that when the Title is clicked nothing happens. Any Ideas? The data is there as when I take away the .hidden css class I can see it.

```
$(".showRow").click(function(){
    descId= $(this).data('id');
    $('#desc_'+descId).dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 500
    });

});
```

I am making a TV Guide, When the Title is clicked on the cell I want a popup to show up with the description of the Title, however I can only make all of the descriptions show up and not just the single one that matches the Title, how would I go about doing this?

HTML

```
 <table id="chart">
      <thead><th>Start</th><th>End</th><th>Title</th></thead><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody>
    </table>
hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "xml/tvguide.xml" ,
        dataType: "xml" ,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            rowNum = 1;
            $(data).find('tvguide channel[id="bbconemonday"] programme').each(function() {

            var title = $(this).find('title').text();
            var desc = $(this).find('desc').text();
            var start = $(this).find('start').text();
            var end = $(this).find('end').text();
            $('<tr data-id="'+rowNum+'" class="showRow"></tr>').html('<td>'+start+'</td><td>'+end+'</td><td title="'+desc+'">'+title+'<div class="hidden" id="desc_'+rowNum+'">'+desc+'</div></td>').appendTo('#chart');
            rowNum++

        });
```

XML SAMPLE

```
    <tvguide>
    <channel id="bbconemonday">
    <programme>
<desc>
The latest news, sport, business and weather from the BBC's Breakfast team. Also in HD. [S] Including regional news at 25 and 55 minutes past each hour.
</desc>
<title>Breakfast</title>
<end>0915</end>
<start>0600</start>
 </programme>
 <programme>
<desc>
13/20. Matt Allwright investigates the activities of conmen, revealing the fake batteries being used in mobile phones, cameras and laptops. Also in HD. [S]
</desc>
<title>Fake Britain</title>
<end>1000</end>
<start>0915</start>
 </programme>
 <programme>
<desc>
Martin Roberts and Lucy Alexander visit a cottage in Devon, a ground floor flat in London and a house in Lancashire. They find out how much each went for at auction. [S]
</desc>
<title>Homes Under the Hammer</title>
<end>1100</end>
<start>1000</start>
 </programme>
 <programme>
<desc>
8/10. Series which sees insurance fraudsters caught on camera. A convicted drug dealer thinks a bump on the head will give him a bumper payout. Also in HD. [S]
</desc>
<title>Claimed and Shamed</title>
<end>1130</end>
<start>1100</start>
 </programme>
 <programme>
<desc>
8/10. Documentary following life on the English Channel. A band of eco-fishermen from Weymouth help preserve the channel's fish stocks by using traditional fishing methods. Also in HD. [S]
</desc>
<title>Channel Patrol</title>
<end>1215</end>
<start>1130</start>
 </programme>
 <programme>
<subtitle>Horncastle</subtitle>
<desc>
Tim Wonnacott and the teams hunt for bargains in the historic town of Horncastle, and Tim pays a visit to the Birmingham Museum and Art Gallery. Also in HD. [AD,S]
</desc>
<title>Bargain Hunt</title>
<end>1300</end>
<start>1215</start>
 </programme>
<programme>
<desc>
The latest national and international news stories from the BBC News team, followed by weather. Also in HD. [S]
</desc>
<title>BBC News at One</title>
<end>1330</end>
<start>1300</start>
</programme>
<programme>
<desc>
The latest news, sport and weather from London. [S]
</desc>
<title>BBC London News</title>
<end>1345</end>
<start>1330</start>
</programme>
<programme>
<subtitle>Victim</subtitle>
<desc>
Drama series. A seemingly straightforward home visit takes an incredibly dark turn for Niamh. The documentary filming doesn't go to plan for Howard. Also in HD. [AD,S]
</desc>
<title>Doctors</title>
<end>1415</end>
<start>1345</start>
</programme>
<programme>
<desc>
8/10. The Ties of the Past: A life model is found murdered at the start of a painting class. Also in HD. [AD,S]
</desc>
<title>The Doctor Blake Mysteries</title>
<end>1510</end>
<start>1415</start>
</programme>
<programme>
<subtitle>West of Scotland</subtitle>
<desc>
Nicki Chapman travels through the west of Scotland, helping an animal-loving couple find their perfect country home. While there, Nicki tries her hand at curling. Also in HD. [AD,S]
</desc>
<title>Escape to the Country</title>
<end>1555</end>
<start>1510</start>
</programme>
<programme>
<desc>
3/6. Celebratory Food: Recipes include slow roast duck with aromatic crispy skin, and gin and tonic granita. Also in HD. [AD,S]
</desc>
<title>Tom Kerridge's Proper Pub Food</title>
<end>1625</end>
<start>1555</start>
</programme>
<programme>
<desc>
7/23. Tavistock: Paul Martin and the team visit sunny Tavistock where Phillip Serrell and Charlie Ross examine people's heirlooms. Paul takes a look around Endsleigh Gardens, just down the road. [S]
</desc>
<title>Flog It!</title>
<end>1715</end>
<start>1625</start>
</programme>
<programme>
<desc>
Quiz in which contestants try to score as few points as possible by plumbing the depths of their general knowledge to come up with the answers no-one else can think of. Also in HD. [S]
</desc>
<title>Pointless</title>
<end>1800</end>
<start>1715</start>
</programme>
<programme>
<desc>
The latest national and international news stories from the BBC News team, followed by weather. Also in HD. [S]
</desc>
<title>BBC News at Six</title>
<end>1830</end>
<start>1800</start>
</programme>
<programme>
<desc>
The latest news, sport and weather from London. [S]
</desc>
<title>BBC London News</title>
<end>1900</end>
<start>1830</start>
</programme>
<programme>
<desc>
If it's got Britain talking then it will get talked about on The One Show. Presented by Matt Baker and Alex Jones. Also in HD. [S] Then BBC News.
</desc>
<title>The One Show</title>
<end>2000</end>
<start>1900</start>
</programme>
<programme>
<desc>
8/20. School-based drama. Allie convinces Vaughan to send Justin to a boarding school in an attempt to keep him away from Tiffany but the young lovers have plans of their own. Also in HD. [AD,S]
</desc>
<title>Waterloo Road</title>
<end>2100</end>
<start>2000</start>
</programme>
<programme>
<desc>
9/14. Ten Years of Discount Buying: To test their negotiation skills, the candidates must buy nine items which have featured in previous years' tasks at the best possible prices. Also in HD. [S]
</desc>
<title>The Apprentice</title>
<end>2200</end>
<start>2100</start>
</programme>
    </channel>
    </tvguide>
```

EDIT:Added in Silverhunter code. Still stuck on the .click

Comment: can you post a bigger block of the xml? one that contains more programme sections for the id="bbconmonday"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your each function is working and propagating your table rows correctly with one data item each iteration then I would try the following.

set a hidden div to contain your description. Make a class called hidden in your css

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Add the hidden div in your appended table row and add an identifier that we can use in our ID's. Ill call it rowNum. We us rowNum to identify our description div. In order to let the system know which description div to show we will also put the rowNum in our tr data attribute to be retrieved on click.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "xml/tvguide.xml" ,
        dataType: "xml" ,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            rowNum = 1;
            $(data).find('tvguide channel[id="bbconemonday"] programme').each(function() {

            var title = $(this).find('title').text();
            var desc = $(this).find('desc').text();
            var start = $(this).find('start').text();
            var end = $(this).find('end').text();
            $('<tr data-id="'+rowNum+'" class="showRow"></tr>').html('<td>'+start+'</td><td>'+end+'</td><td title="'+desc+'">'+title+'<div class="hidden" id="desc_'+rowNum+'">'+desc+'</div></td>').appendTo('#chart');
            rowNum++

        });
    });
```

Set the click handler outside of your Ajax function to handle any row that is clicked. Because we put a data attribute in our tr that has the ID we need we can access our description div using it.

```
$("#chart").on('click', 'tr.showrow', function(){
    descId= $(this).data('id');
    $('#desc_'+descId).dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 500
    });

});
```

Comment: The .click is not doing anything for me any ideas? the data is there as I can see it when I take out the .hidden CSS class. Your help is greatly appreciated BTW.

Comment: @yolad As user26409021 said the .on() is better to use here. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `on` insteaf of `click` event handler, like below

```
$("table").on('click','.showRow',function(){
descId= $(this).data('id');
$('#desc_'+descId).dialog({
    modal: true,
    width: 500
});
```

});

Comment: Nope still nothing when I Click

Comment: It's working now.I had the table name wrong, thank you so much.